# Tableau counting multiple blanks

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dataset containing roughly 50 columns. I want to check the data inputs and show how many blanks/if any are in each column.

I originally started using calculated fields for columns and using  sum(if isnull([column] then 1 else 0 end)). This works but doesn’t seem very efficient if I want to do it for multiple columns.

Tried doing a pivot table as well however I need the data in it’s original form for other analysis I would like to do.

Would appreciate any help.

Thanks
Fiona

Comment: When you say it doesn't seem efficient do you mean is it slow? Does it work? How big is the dataset?

Comment: If pivoting works, then make two data connections. One for each of your needs.